# Can't find documentation for Minecraft Education Edition

Tags: minecraft

I'd like to learn more about the codebuilder in Minecraft Education Edition.
I'm looking for any comprehensive documentation from Microsoft or 3rd party. Right now I just try to guess from the blocks and the code completion recommendations in the Python section. It's trial and error with emphasis on error.
Any resource is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://education.minecraft.net/wp-content/uploads/Code_Connection_API.pdf

This is the entire documentation of Minecraft Education Edition.

Another useful link:- https://education.minecraft.net/en-us/lessons/coding-introduction

Usefulness - Introduces students to computer science and coding, provide an overview to Minecraft Education Edition and the MakeCode coding editor.

Comment: Did this help you?